# How can I convert date string to data in javascript in different timezone?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a Date string to `date` object in javascript. What I receive is something like:

```
utc='2021-02-03T02:44:51.118Z'.  # time in utc

local='2021-02-03T12:44:51.118Z' # time in local timezone
```

for above two strings, each of which represent a different timezone. How can I create a Date object from them to represent the right timezone? Ideally I'd like to convert them to `epoch` format but don't know how to calculate offset correctly.

I have looked at `getTimezoneOffset` method but it doesn't consider daylight saving time.

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316657/how-to-update-the-time-every-second-using-setinterval-without-the-time-flash/56317035#56317035 -- if not that one, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818270/changing-list-of-time-zone-offset-numbers-to-current-times-with-javascript/65818776#65818776

Comment: You can get current timestamp using `+ new Date()`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/221297/9416618).

Comment: You can convert the UTC date into a timestamp directly using `new Date("place date here").getTime()` because the dates and times you're using are formatted in ISO 8601 format. Note: this will return it in millisecond resolution. To get a proper timestamp (in seconds), use this instead: `Math.floor(new Date("place date here").getTime() / 1000)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9873379/9416618). You must use the UTC/GMT time to get a correct timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date` object and method `toLocaleString()`.

When you use the string `'2021-02-03T02:44:51.118Z'` or `'2021-02-03T12:44:51.118Z'`, they are all UTC time.

When you use the string `'2021-02-03T12:44:51.118+10:00'`, it is time zone +10:00 (Dumont d'Urville Station).

To convert UTC to local time zone, use this code:

```js
let time = "2021-02-03T02:44:51.118Z"

let t = new Date(time)
console.log(t.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Antarctica/DumontDUrville"}));
```

To convert local time to UTC, use this code:

```js
let local = "2021-02-03T12:44:51.118+10:00"
let t = new Date(local)
console.log(t.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "UTC"}));
```

**Note:**

- `Z` means *"zero hour offset"* also known as "Zulu time" (UTC)
- Can see list of local **timeZone** code at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)