# Formatting and parsing a date string without timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If I'm in a timezone a few hours before midnight and I try

`new Date("2020-03-30T00:00:00.000Z")`

it will result in

`Sun Mar 29 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`

then I realized even

`new Date("2020-03-30")`

in the wrong timezone will result in the exact same conversion. I have a similar problem with moment.js constructed from similar strings in similar timezones, when I try to call the .format() method it will do a conversion first, sometimes resulting in the wrong day of the month.

How can I format such a date initialized like this and not have to deal with timezone conversions? eg work with just the "raw" date it was initialized from

Comment: One of these two answers will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818270/changing-list-of-time-zone-offset-numbers-to-current-times-with-javascript/65818776#65818776 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316657/how-to-update-the-time-every-second-using-setinterval-without-the-time-flash/56317035#56317035

Comment: This may sound weird, but why do you need a `Date` in the first place? You can always create your own class or store year, month and date in an object.

Comment: I need the natural ordering of a Date plus APIs are expecting a Date object